# Is it already possible to do joins from Mongo 3.2 in Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, left-join

As in the question, I did not find any information whether Mongoose has already added this feature, but has anyone tried using this in Node.js application? Is the performance ok and is it stable enough for production use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $lookup feature is available from version 4.3 onwards, see this ticket https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3532. As Mongo 3.2 is now a stable release and as no big changes were required to implement this in Mongoose, the feature should be relatively stable. Regarding performance, this is hard to comment on without looking at a concrete example.